# Saving XML with encoded text using PHP's DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, decode, encode

I am attempting to use DOMDocument() to load some XML.  I would like to save the XML with encoded values but it keeps decoding it when calling saveXML().

Please see the code below:

```
 $xml_str = "<Name>o&#39;rielly, o-no, s~sdf&quot;sdf&#39; one test</Name>";
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
 $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
 if($dom->loadXML($xml_str)) {                      
      $saved_XML     = $dom->saveXML();
      print_r("xml -> {$saved_XML}\n");  
 }
```

The print_r statement will return:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <Name>o'rielly, o-no, s~sdf"sdf' one test</Name>
```

I am trying to make it return:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
 <Name>o&#39;rielly, o-no, s~sdf&quot;sdf&#39; one test</Name>
```

Is this possible to do?

Any help will be welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOM will escape all needed characters, but not the others. Quotes in text nodes do not need to be escaped, so DOM will not escape them. If loaded with an XML parser the result will be equal.

It depends on the expected result. If you want to read the special characters, just let DOM escape the needed characters and ignore the others. It will make the XML easier to read  and smaller. If you need to read the entities, you will have to use a CDATA section or encode them.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<Names>
   <Name>o'rielly, o-no, s~sdf"sdf' one test</Name>
   <Name>o&#39;rielly, o-no, s~sdf&quot;sdf&#39; one test</Name>
   <Name><![CDATA[o&#39;rielly, o-no, s~sdf&quot;sdf&#39; one test]]></Name>
   <Name>o&amp;#39;rielly, o-no, s~sdf&amp;quot;sdf&amp;#39; one test</Name>
</Names>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

echo "Default:\n";
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//Name[1])'));
echo "Entities:\n";
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//Name[2])'));
echo "CDATA Section:\n";
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//Name[3])'));
echo "Encoded Entities:\n";
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//Name[4])'));
```

Output:

```
Default:
string(35) "o'rielly, o-no, s~sdf"sdf' one test"
Entities:
string(35) "o'rielly, o-no, s~sdf"sdf' one test"
CDATA Section:
string(48) "o&#39;rielly, o-no, s~sdf&quot;sdf&#39; one test"
Encoded Entities:
string(48) "o&#39;rielly, o-no, s~sdf&quot;sdf&#39; one test"
```

If you create the nodes with the proper create* methods, DOM will take care of the encoding so you can read the same value that you saved.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$root = $dom->appendChild($dom->createElement('Names'));
$root
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement('Name'))
  ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("O'Reilly"));
$root
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement('Name'))
  ->appendChild($dom->createTextNode("O&#39;Reilly"));
$root
  ->appendChild($dom->createElement('Name'))
  ->appendChild($dom->createCDataSection("O&#39;Reilly"));

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Names>
  <Name>O'Reilly</Name>
  <Name>O&amp;#39;Reilly</Name>
  <Name><![CDATA[O&#39;Reilly]]></Name>
</Names>
```